GremlinQ: How to Filter a Vertex Based on Multiple Conditions
I need to filter a Conversation vertex where both senderId and receiverId must match the outgoing edge BelongsTo. Here’s what I imagine the query should look like:
public async Task<ConversationMessage?> SendMessageToUser(string senderId, string receiverId, string messageContentValue)
{
    var conversation = gremlinQuerySource.V<Conversation>()
        .Where(conversation => conversation.OutE<BelongsTo>()
            .InV<Account>()
            .Where(account => account.Id == senderId) &&
            conversation.OutE<BelongsTo>()
            .InV<Account>()
            .Where(account => account.Id == receiverId))
        .Debug();
}

I’m not sure how to achieve this using GremlinQ. I’ve been searching the internet for hours and asked ChatGPT for an answer, but haven’t had any luck.

Could you please add sample data and the expectation out of your query. Currently looking at the question it is not entirely what your datamodel is.

Never mind, I found the answer. I must call the Where clause separately for each condition to make the traversal valid. If I group the conditions in a single Where and And clauses, it forces all conditions to match on the same traversal path, which is impossible since senderId points to one account and receiverId points to another. The original code that compile looks like this:
                conversation = await gremlinQuerySource
                    .V<Account>()
                    .Where(account => account.Id == senderId)
                    .OutE<Has>()
                    .InV<Conversation>()
                    .And(
                    query => query.Where(conversation => conversation.IsDirectMessage),
                    query => query.OutE<BelongsTo>().InV<Account>().Where(account => account.Id == senderId),
                    query => query.OutE<BelongsTo>().InV<Account>().Where(account => account.Id == receiverId))
.FirstAsync();

The revised code looks like this:
                conversation = await gremlinQuerySource
                    .V<Account>()
                    .Where(account => account.Id == senderId)
                    .OutE<Has>()
                    .InV<Conversation>()
                    .Where(conversation => conversation.IsDirectMessage)
                    .Where(conversation => conversation.OutE<BelongsTo>().InV<Account>().Where(a => a.Id == senderId))
                    .Where(conversation => conversation.OutE<BelongsTo>().InV<Account>().Where(a => a.Id == receiverId))
                    .FirstAsync();

